# Windows Server 2012 Cluser on VMware esxi 5.5: Rebooting passive node causes san reset on active node

Tags: vmware-esxi, cluster

I'm running a SQL Cluster on windows server 2012 on VMWare 5.5 and find that when I restart the passive node to install a patch, the active node is affected. This appears to be covered by the kb article http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=2033174&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=416079996&stateId=1%200%20399670784 but this doesn't seem correct behavior for a cluster - in that updating the passive node should affect the active node.